# Why do I get an AG_E_NETWORK_ERROR in Silverlight on my local machine

Tags: silverlight, localhost, bitmapimage

I am hosting my Silverlight app in SharePoint 2010, which is running on my machine. Suddenly my images stopped showing up, and after a lot of fiddling, I tracked the issue down to an AG_E_NETWORK_ERROR.

- Searching all over the internet says
  I can't do cross-whatever in
  Silverlight, but that is not my
  issue.
- My site is on http://my-site/,
  and the image url is
  http://my-site/image.gif.

The worst part is this used to work. But I have no idea what has changed since then.

Comment: @Thomas: It that "Update" is the answer then please add it as an answer to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Gif-images are not supported in Silverlight](http://dotnetslackers.com/IIS/re-116415_Silverlight_Server_Configuration.aspx)